# Symfony 5.0: make:migration or doctrine:schema:update --force only creates id columns but not other fields defined in entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Something very strange happened to my right now...

I use the newest symfony CLI tool and created a project and an entity which has a field "name".
When i update or migrate the schema, only the column "id" is generated.

`Symfony CLI version v4.11.2 (c) 2017-2019 Symfony SAS`

```
$ symfony new --full test
$ cd test
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
$ php bin/console make:entity Test
$ php bin/console make:migration
$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

The created entity:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestRepository")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The created migration (only column id is generated):

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20191127110625 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE test');
    }
}
```

I have a mysql server running at localhost:

```
Server version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 (Ubuntu)
```

The connection string looks like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/test?serverVersion=5.7
```

Also `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` instead of migration gives me the same result.

Any suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: I made a fresh 5.0.0 project, copy/pasted your Test entity and schema update as well as migration all seemed to work fine.  I suppose you could try a bin/console doctrine:database:drop just in case the database has an existing test table.  But I doubt it will help.

Comment: The migration itself works fine - no error message.
But the sql statement in the Migration file is not complete - based on the entity it should also insert a "name" column but it only inserts a "id" column (see "CREATE TABLE ..." in function up.

When you reproduce it and have a look at the mysql table, is there a column for "name" after migration/updating schema?
I already tried to drop the database, remove/recreate the migration and also tried without migration and doctrine:schema:update --force after dropping/creating the database.

Comment: Yep.  I get: $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) blah blah blah Normally I might suspect some third party bundle interfering with things but from what you described in your question, you made a fresh 5.0.0 project and just added one entity.  Quite a mystery.  Good luck.

Comment: Clearing the cache solved it. Still strange behaviour as i tried it further times by creating new 5.0 projects.
Clearing cache seems the new "have you tried turn it off on on again" ;)

Answer (score 2):

After a `php bin/console cache:clear` everything worked as expected.